# How to wait simultaneously on both recv() and sem_wait()?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, posix, semaphore

I have a thread that has to be unblocked either when data is ready to be read through recv() or when the semaphore S is signalled.

Is there any way do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no lock like `WaitForMultipleObjects()` in posix you have only limited options.

A. use [select(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) and be notified on socket change events

B. or [poll(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) and be notified on file descriptor events

or C. use some library implementation like libevent

Answer (score 1):

You can replace POSIX semaphore with futex and select/poll on both the socket and the futex.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem is to use a pair of sockets instead of a semaphore.  In particular, you can call socketpair() to get a pair of connected sockets; give one of the sockets to thread A and the other socket to thread B, and then either thread can wake up the the other thread (which is blocking inside select()/poll()/etc) by sending a byte on its socket.